# Have to click twice to submit a form with form validator and AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, validation

I've some trouble using form-validator (JQuery) on submiting a form. It requires a second click to fire the onSucces callback of my form validator object.

```
function formSender(form, valid){
    $.validate({
        form : form,
        validateOnBlur : false,
        scrollToTopOnError : false,
        onSuccess : function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: $(form).attr("action"),
                dataType: 'json',
                async: true,
                cache: false,
                data: $().serialize(),
                success: function(jsonData,textStatus,jqXHR){
                    if(jsonData.hasError == false){
                        $(form).fadeToggle("fast", "linear");
                        $(valid).html(jsonData.message) ;
                    }
                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                    $(valid).html(jsonData.message) ;
                }
            }
        )}
    });
}

$("#form-partners").on("submit", function(event) {
    ga('send', 'event', 'formulaire', 'clic', 'contact');
    formSender('#form-partners', '#confirmation-message-partenaire');
    customPreventDefault(event);
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: You probably aren't setting up the submit process until after the first submit.

Answer (score 0):

I the end, i had to dissociate the submit event of element #form-partners from the auto trigger of the validate pluggin form-validator like this :

```
$.validate({
    form : '#form-partners',
    errorMessagePosition : 'top',
    validateOnBlur : false,
    scrollToTopOnError : false,
    showHelpOnFocus : false,
    language : myLanguage,
    onSuccess : function (form) {
        return $.sendFormDataViaAJAX(form, '#form-partners', '#confirmation-message-partenaire');
    }
});        

$.sendFormDataViaAJAX = function(form, formName, valid) {
    $.ajax(
    {
        /. Content ./
    }

    $("#form-partners").on("submit", function(event) {
        ga('send', 'event', 'formulaire', 'clic', 'contact');
        customPreventDefault(event);
    });
}
```